# Send a value for a checkbox when it is unchecked

Tags: php, checkbox

To give you an idea of what I am after. I have items that have "info" to them, well say if I check a box to show Model, I want to be able to go in at a later date and uncheck it.

Is there anyway that you can uncheck a checkbox and have it be stored as 0 in the database?

Here is my input ( I have 10 of these )

```
<input type="checkbox" name="showmodel" <?php if ($showmodel == '1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />
```

this is how I am trying to update it

```
$query = "UPDATE `new_equip` SET `featured`='1',`showmanu`='1',`showmodel`='1' "WHERE `id`='$id' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: if the chekbox isn't checked, the value would be 0, just use the passed value to fill the database.

Comment: Right, but if the checkbox is checked, is there a way to go in and uncheck it and have it update in the database?

Comment: I don't get it, what you want ;) if you want to update the database use something like this: `UPDATE foo SET booleanField = ':checkboxValue' WHERE id = ':theId'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I passed trough the same issue and i solved like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="permission[<?php echo $data->permission_id; ?>]" value="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[<?php echo $data->permission_id; ?>]" <?php if($data->permission == 'on') { echo 'checked'; } ?> >
```

Comment: That's how we solved this problem in the 90s and as far as I know it's still an accepted practice.